# How to get the (Greatest Common Divisor)GCD of Doubles

Tags: algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

This is a simple task but i can't seem to figure out how to do it

Here is a sample function structure

```
private double GetGCD(double num1, double num2)
{
    //should return the GCD of the two double
}
```

test data

```
   num1 = 6;
   num2 = 3;
   *return value must be 3*

   num1 = 8.8;
   num2 = 6.6;
   *return value must be 2.2*

   num1 = 5.1;
   num2 = 8.5;
   *return value must be 1.7*
```

note: maximum decimal places is 1.
      programming language is not important. i just need the algorthm

please help.. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one decimal place, multiply the numbers by 10, convert them to integers and run an [integer GCD function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

This will also save you [floating point precision errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962640/what-algorithm-does-python-employ-in-fractions-gcd), the base Euclidean algorithm in Python (for integers!) is:

```java
def gcd(a, b):
    """Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.

    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

So, your code should be something like:

```java
 def gcd_floats(x,y):
     return gcd( int(x*10), int(y*10) )/10
```

Comment: can you help me with the algo.. im really stumped. i think i deteriorated in math =(

Comment: Look it up in the attached link, or search for GCD algorithm. Almost any algorithms you'll find is designed for integers.

Comment: made this one and it works! thanks private int GCD(int a, int b)
        {
            if (b == 0)
                return a;
            else
                return GCD(b, a % b);
        }

Answer (score 3):

When it's 8.8 and 6.6 then you can find the GCD of 88 and 66 and then divide it by 10.

Answer (score 1):

There are zillions of places on the web to find code for the GCD function.  Since, strictly speaking, it is only defined on integers, I suggest you multiply your doubles by 10, work out the GCD and divide the result by 10.  This will save you a world of pain arising from using the wrong datatype.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the GCD of a number which is not discrete. However, your case is more specific. If your input is not a Double, but a Decimal, then you can convert it to a Fraction, multiply the denominators, find the GCD of the numerators and divide back down. That is:

```
8.800 = 8800/1000 = 44/5 (by GCD)
6.600 = 6600/1000 = 33/5 (by GCD)

5.100 = 5100/1000 = 51/10
8.500 = 8500/1000 = 17/2
```

It's useful to simplify the fractions in this step in order to avoid our numbers getting too large.

Move to a common denominator:

```
44*5/5*5 = 220/25
33*5/5*5 = 165/25

51*2/2*10 = 102/20
17*10/2*10 = 170/20
```

GCD of numerator:

```
gcd(165,220) = 55

gcd(102,170) = 34
```

So answers are 55/25 and 34/20.

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 methods

1. The traditional division method
2. Euclid's method

```
    class GCD
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int a = (int)(1.2*10);
            int b = (int)(3.4*10);

            System.out.println((float)gcd(a, b)/10);
        }
    // 1

        public static int gcd(int a, int b)
        {
            if(b==0)
                return a;
            else
                return gcd(b, (int)a%b);
        }

    // 2
        public static int gcd(int a, int b)
        {
            int k,i;

            if(a>b)
                k = b;
            else
                k = a;

            for(i=k; i>=2; i--)
            {
                if( (a%i==0)&&(b%i==0) )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
```